# Mex error: 'object' can not be used when making a shared object

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, linker-errors, mex

I am trying to compile a mex script. 
The error I get is:

```
ld: selfintersect.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against 
`_ZTVSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE' can not be used when making a 
shared object; recompile with -fPIC
selfintersect.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

Reading answers to similar questions, I understand this error is caused  since I am trying to compile a shared object but am using a static one in the linking. However the error is quite cryptic - I cannot understand which is the static object I should recompile as a dynamic one. Below is the calls mex is making to gcc:

```
gcc -c  -Isrc -I/usr/local/include/ -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 
-I/usr/local/igl/libigl/include 
-I/local/apps/linux-2.2-i386/matlab/matlab-8.5.0.197613/extern/include 
-DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -std=c++11  -DMEX -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "selfintersect.cpp"
```

and then linking:

```
gcc -O -pthread -shared -Wl,
--version-script,/local/apps/linux-2.2-i386/matlab/matlab-8.5.0.197613/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map 
-Wl,--no-undefined -o  "selfintersect.mexa64"  selfintersect.o  
-L/home/user/mylibs/CGAL-4.6/lib -lCGAL -lCGAL_Core -lgmp -lmpfr 
-lboost_thread -lboost_system -Wl,-rpath-link,
/local/apps/linux-2.2-i386/matlab/matlab-8.5.0.197613/bin/glnxa64 
-L/local/apps/linux-2.2-i386/matlab/matlab-8.5.0.197613/bin/glnxa64 
-lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
```

Comment: What is output upon the invocation of `g++ --version`? GCC < 5.x didn't support `codecvt` and the like, IIRC

Comment: @nabijaczleweli `gcc (GCC) 4.8.2` - I am not sure I understand the relation to `codecvt`. Sorry for the stupid question, I am not an expert in C++ to say th e least...

Comment: Did you try recompiling with "-fPIC"?